# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, mysql, database

Error is:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'book_id =
>   'DSP123'' at line 1
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2427)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2345)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2330)
>           at Frames.Books.jButton2ActionPerformed(Books.java:424)
>           at Frames.Books.access$300(Books.java:26)
>           at Frames.Books$4.actionPerformed(Books.java:181)
>           at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
>           at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
>           at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
>           at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
>           at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
>           at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6263)
>           at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
>           at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6028)
>           at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
>           at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
>           at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
>           at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
>           at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4574)
>           at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
>           at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
>           at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
>           at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
>           at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)

Code is:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String bookid = jTextField2.getText();
    String doi = "";
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    doi = doi + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    String sql = "insert into library.issue values ('"+ bookid + "','librarian','"+ username + "','" + doi + "')";
    try
    {
        int i = st.executeUpdate(sql);
        if(i>0)
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"BOOK IS ISSUED","SUCCESS",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        else
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"problem in issuing book","FAILURE",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        bookid = bookid.toUpperCase();
        String sql1 = "update library.books set status = " + 1 + "where book_id = '" + bookid + "'";
        PreparedStatement pstmt=c.prepareStatement(sql1);
        int j= pstmt.executeUpdate() ;
        //int j = st.executeUpdate(sql1);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert a space before `where`:

```
String sql1 = "update library.books set status = " + 1 
      + " where book_id = '" + bookid + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

check once it should be

```
String sql1 = "update library.books set status =  1 where book_id = '" + bookid + "'";
```